# Incrementing a struct value in a for loop returns the same value each time

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct

I'm just trying to run this simple line of code:

```
for (Client c : clients) {
    c.timeSinceLastPacket++;
    std::cout << c.timeSinceLastPacket << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately this always returns 1 after the increment. If I put a print before the increment it returns 0.

Here is my struct:

```
struct Client {
    int timeSinceLastPacket = 0;
    sf::IpAddress ip;
    unsigned short port = 0;
    unsigned short id = 0;
};
```

I'm using SFML.

Here's what I've tried:

- Changed the ++ to += 1
- Removed every instance in which the packet's value is defined as 0 (this can be seen in the code I have linked)
- Changed the value of the packet to float
- I should also mention that my original intention was to use sf::Time but that didn't work either
- If I replace c with clients[0] it works fine

The code isn't too long but I don't want to put it in the question. I'll link you to it here:

[Server.h](http://pastebin.com/UFeTSKP4)

[Server.cpp](http://pastebin.com/xiGstu45)

Comment: _"The code isn't too long but I don't want to put it in the question. I'll link you to it here:"_ Instead of doing that, construct a [MCVE].

Comment: putting code on external sites and your question is in the risk of being closed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for (Client c : clients) {
```

Here you make a copy, named `c`. Your original in `clients` is unaffected.

If you want to mutate the original elements, use a reference:

```
for (Client& c : clients) {
```

Comment: You beat my by 10 seconds!

Comment: @DavidLively: 29 actually ;)

Comment: What's a factor of 3x between friends? :)

Comment: @DavidLively: Depends what's being multiplied ^_^

Comment: First SO gaffaw of the morning. :)

Answer (score 4):

By typing the loop variable as `Client`, you're making a copy of the element in the array on every iteration. Changes within the loop update the copy, not the original item stored in `clients`.

Make it a reference instead:

```
for (Client& c : clients) {
```

Unlike Java or C#, C++ defaults to value types rather than references, so you must explicitly state that you want a reference (or a pointer, but the syntax is slightly messier).

Using a non-reference type here can also lead to some perf issues if the type is complex, or performs significant processing its copy constructor. (That's not really a concern for the type you've outlined here, but can be an issue in other cases.)